# Calculating all possible combinations

Tags: php, math, permutation

I'm trying to calculate the number of possible combinations of clothing for different types of characters in a game as well as listing those combinations or a PHP script to generate the filenames.

I have 5 different type of characters (mexican, asian, american, african).

There are 3 different sizes for each character (small, medium, large)

There are 9 different sets of clothing (shirt, shorts, shoes).

The gear are grouped into the following order:

```
Shirt (A) | X1  X2  X3 | Y1  Y2  Y3 | Z1 Z2 Z3
Short (B) | X1  X2  X3 | Y1  Y2  Y3 | Z1 Z2 Z3
Shoes (C) | X1  X2  X3 | Y1  Y2  Y3 | Z1 Z2 Z3
```

Small is X1 - X3,
Medium is Y1 -Y3,
Large is Z1 - Z3

You have to unlock each type of clothing in sequential order before the next one.

Each group (X, Y, Z) must have all items unlocked before moving forward.

Comment: Exactly what are your question and what are your current attempt?

Comment: 5x3x9= number of combinations

Comment: @fiskfisk: I'd like to find the total number of combinations (as stated in first sentence) and if possible, a list of these combinations.

Comment: so a mexican is not an american? As this is actually a mathematics question (You are asking for the number of [Permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) you might want to go over to mathematics @Waygood already wrote the correct calculation for the number of possible permutations.

Comment: No in this case american is not the same as mexican. The names of the character types are irrelevant. You could call them A, B, C, D instead. 

Waygood's answer is not taking the conditions at the bottom into account.

Comment: I'd take the mathematica tag off of this; I don't believe it applies.  It's easy to calculate all the combinations and/or permutations.  The ordering and "unlocking" behavior would be best encapsulated in an object of some kind.

Comment: @FrankGordon Well, how do you want to take the bottom conditions into account? If there's 3 unlocked items, the 9 in Waygood's equation becomes a three. If you want to generate the permutations, you can loop over each set, as you're only picking one attribute from each set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For algorithms for producing all combinations, see Knuth [The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4, Fascicle 3: Generating All Combinations and Partitions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201853949)